# Algorithm:- Capturing the Drop-off screen from where the user got dropped

Tags: algorithm

I'm building an application where I need to manage the drop-off screen, ie, the screen from where the user killed the application.

One way to solving this problem is to ask the JS client to send an event to the server. The event will be the last successfully executed screen. For eg:- if my application has 10 different screens, then the last screen which was successfully completed by the user, the client will send the server the `screen_name`.

Now when the client wants to know the screen from where the user dropped-off, it can make a GET call and fetch the same.

The cons I see with this solution is:-

1) Dependency on the client for sending an event. If while sending the event, the connection drops-off or the user killed the application(website), then the client has no way to send the event again. In this way, the user will come back again to the same screen which was successfully completed

2) Increased number of network calls.

**Is there any way in which server can itself handle the drop-off state? I have RESTful APIs.**

Comment: Whenever a new screen is requested, you can save the information in a current_screen variable on the server(also do this for back button), once the user drops a screen, the current_screen would be the last screen.

Comment: App screens are not requested from the server. They are coded inside the SDK itself.

Comment: are you talking about android. Anyway you can just make a simple request at the start of each activity

Comment: Both android and website. Making what request? What would be the purpose of this request?

Comment: post request, send the current activities name or ID, response can be null. At the server, the name or ID can be used to track which screen is being used and was last used.

Comment: This is the same solution that I proposed.

Comment: Any other apart from?

Comment: for phone applications (android) you can store the current activity using [Shared preferences](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage#pref). From the docs: `The key-value pairs are written to XML files that persist across user sessions, even if your app is killed. You can manually specify a name for the file or use per-activity files to save your data.`

Comment: What if the app is uninstalled and then re-installed again? The data in the shared preference will be wiped out.

Comment: you can use some of these ideas for the app to remember its data. [link](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/158508/how-do-some-android-apps-remember-that-this-is-not-the-first-time-they-are-being)

Comment: In simple terms, you can use the local storage or the cloud storage to save the current window and do a periodic sync as well, if that helps.